# what's the meaning of "q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"

Tags: http, http-headers, httpwebrequest

i am studying http protocol. when i use fiddler to catch a request, i find some arguments special.

part of http request:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryiUs1bDxxBwTvwCxS
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,\*/\*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: GBK,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

What does the arguments `q=0.9,\*/\*;q=0.8` in the Accept-header, `q=0.8` in the Accept-Language-header and `q=0.7,*;q=0.3` in the Accept-Charset-header mean?

Comment: in Accept-Language: zh-CN
but in Accept-Charset: GBK?
why how this works?

Answer (score 13):

Excerpt from this page http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html:

> Note: Use of the "q" parameter name to separate media type
>         parameters from Accept extension parameters is due to historical
>         practice. Although this prevents any media type parameter named
>         "q" from being used with a media range, such an event is believed
>         to be unlikely given the lack of any "q" parameters in the IANA
>         media type registry and the rare usage of any media type
>         parameters in Accept. Future media types are discouraged from
>         registering any parameter named "q".

This is basically a way to give the browser a way to indicate preference for a certain media type.

Answer (score 5):

I think

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language

has better explanation to the question.

Quote from the website:

### Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

;q= (q-factor weighting)

*Any value placed in an order of preference expressed using a relative quality value called weight.*